# How to authenticate a Rails API with Google JWTs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

On the frontend, using React and the Google Login Button, the user logs in to my application. Google returns the user's JWT to a callback URL on the frontend, encoded. I then deliver this JWT on each request to a Rails API and want the rails API to decode and verify this JWT, and if it is verified successfully, return the data that API endpoint is supposed to give.

I am currently using this code:

```
def google_public_key
  x509 = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new ENV["GOOGLE_CERT"]
  x509.public_key
end
```

The env var is described like this: https://gist.github.com/Connorelsea/c6b91a4b4b6889294fd4e2fcacb06564

I am getting this error: `OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError (nested asn1 error)`

If I do not verify, I can read the content of the JWT. From the JWT website it can be decoded, but not verified, as well.

Comment: did you search for the error, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263835/getting-opensslx509certificateerror-nested-asn1-error-on-ruby

Comment: Yes. People expressed formatting concerns and we tried their fixes. None worked.

Comment: it doesn't look like just formatting concerns

Comment: I am getting the JWT from google. Using the google login button. So I am not doing any of the JWT making myself.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and solved by setting the public_key as Pkey object not as a string in the constructor, try:

```
def google_public_key
  x509 = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new 
  x509.public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new ENV["GOOGLE_CERT"]
end
```